# Product of Matrix with Adjugate equals Determinant by Unit Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> Let $ A $ be a square matrix of order $ n $, $ \operatorname {adj} ( A ) $ be the adjugate of $ A $ and $ \det ( A ) $ be the determinant of $ A $. Then
> $$ \big( \operatorname {adj} ( A ) \big) A = \det ( A ) I = A \big( \operatorname {adj} ( A ) \big) \text , $$
> where $ I $ is the unit mtrix of order $ n $.

[Proofwiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Product_of_Matrix_with_Adjugate_equals_Determinant_by_Unit_Matrix) has no proof, my textbook lacks it as well. Can anyone help?

Comment: The only facts you need to prove this result are the [laplace expansion of the determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) and the fact that a matrix with a repeated row/column has determinant $0$.

Comment: How does the fact that  a matrix with a repeated row/column has determinant 0 helps with this proof?

Comment: With this fact, we can see that the off-diagonal entries of $\operatorname{adj}(A)A$ will be zero