# how is the formula for determining the adjoint of a matrix derived?

Tags: matrices

I'm learning [how to get the adjoint of a matrix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHzpMgKuI9Q&ab_channel=Don%27tMemorise) using cofactors and the transpose, but how is this formula proven? When I try to google the proof for this, all I get is blog posts on how to get the adjoint of a matrix but not the proof of the formula itself.

Comment: I guess I'm just curious about the origin of the formula as in who discovered it and what its original purpose was. Like how did Einstain figure out E=mc2. I get that it's a definition, but still, there must have been some process to figuring it out and its relation to currently widely used matrix related formulas.

Comment: don't want to be rude or anything, just really curious. :)

Comment: The question is what motivates the definition — it’s a good question.

Comment: It’s funny that the “Don’t Memorise” channel you linked to presents the adjoint matrix in a way that is pure memorization, no motivation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denoting the adjoint of a matrix $A$ by $A^\#$, it is well known that
$$
AA^\# =\text{det}(A)\cdot I,
$$
and in fact this is the main motivation for introducing the adjoint, since it leads to the formula for the inverse of $A$:
$$
A^{-1}=\frac 1{\text{det}(A)}A^\#.
$$
Now it also follows that
$$
A^\#=\text{det}(A)A^{-1}.\tag{1}
$$
This of course only works for invertible matrices but if you work out an appropriate way to compute the right-hand-side of (1) in terms of the entries of $A$, you will arrive at a formula for the adjoint which will  miraculously be valid also for non-invertible matrices!

Comment: For anyone stuck on the proof of  $AA^\#=det(A)I$ ,   you may look at 
Ben Grossmann 's hint [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3921143)